# why can't I test prerelease build on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I have a pre-release build that I have been testing through Test Flight on iTunes Connect. Then I submit another build for **actual release review**, i.e. under `Version`. Normally when I submit a new pre-release build for review, I am blocked from submitting additional testers since all reviews stop until the new build is accepted. This makes visual sense because I can see the green button assigned to the build awaiting approval.

But this time it does not make sense to me. I can see my pre-release build is still in test, but I cannot invite any new users to it. I don't really know why this is happening. I am just wondering if it has anything to do with having an actual new version under review for actual release. Thanks for sharing your experience.

Now I understand that if I have a build ready to publish I will lose access to all previous builds in the pre-release tab. But that is not what is happening. I hope my explanation is clear. If not, please ask any  questions you may have.

Comment: There is sometimes a few hours delay when you upload builds. Give it time to see if that fixes it.

Comment: The pre-release build in question got approved about a week ago and I have been using it to invite testers. The "release" build I submitted about over 24hours ago. It just happens that right now I am trying to invite a new beta tester, and the invitation is not happening. When I click on external testers, there is nothing there. So I add the tester anyway. Still the email invitation is not sent.

Comment: You can't have same tester as internal and external. Remove it from externals testers and the internal invite will show.

Comment: latest ... http://stackoverflow.com/q/33792510/294884