# iTunes Connect Add an iOS build to test - build grayed-out?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

This build HAS finished processing, BUT it is now stuck as a "grayed-out" build. I have never seen anything like this before. Is this a brand new problem on iTunes Connect?

[image]

totally bizarre...

Comment: Got the same issue myself tonight with a build constantly in greyed out status. Usually says processing, but doesn't even say that. Must be an iTunes issue

Comment: np, like you, kinda relieved to know it's not just my build. Good luck with the re-upload and let us know if that fixes it

Comment: Mine's is up now. It eventually went. Took about 2 hours in total

Comment: I've been submitting apps to iTunes for years and there's so often issues, problems, unexplained bugs or the whole thing is just not working. iTunesConnect is a pig.

Comment: fortunately came good after 2.5 hrs but only with the "only change was the build number" extra build....  :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An update from us, due to

(i) adding a new build ("451") which is pointlessly identical other than the build number

(ii) waiting 2.5 hours

[image]

seemed to do the trick.  Interestingly it just skipped or got confused about 450, so maybe there was some problem there.

Answer (score 9):

Who is using Xcode Cloud can have same experience (not possible to select build).

To fix it you need to select **TestFlight and App Store** deployment preparation as it shown in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A build I uploaded more than 3 hours ago just changed from grayed-out to an option. Yet the build that finished processing about an hour ago is still grayed-out. So looks like it may be working with a much greater than normal lag.

Comment: Clearly this "grayed-out" crap is the latest crap from iTunes Connect.  Very distressing.

Comment: Mine just now got un grayed-out.  Took an hour or so of processing on their end i guess...